# Can I fix a chewy beef joint after it's already cooked and sliced?

Tags: beef

Now I have cooked the beef joint & it's cut up into thin slices is there anything I can do to make it less chewy.

Editor's note: let's assume this is some kind of cut meant for roasting, presumably something with a fair amount of connective tissue.

Comment: What cut exactly was this "joint", and how did you slice it?   Across the grain?  How thick are the slices?

Comment: pictures would be very helpful

Comment: I think we should probably answer this assuming that it was a cut meant for roasting, which as far as I know is generally what "joint" means in British English. Something with connective tissue. I don't think this is a duplicate of existing questions, because it's asking how to salvage it afterward, not how to cook it properly in the first place. Dave, I'm editing that into your question; feel free to change it if it's not accurate.

Comment: We still need to know what the cut was... it may be selection that is the primary issue.   High connective tissue is contraindicated except for braising or long low and slow; low connective tissue like filet that is overcooked is essentially unsalvagable.  Then there are the roasts where cooking technique and carving technique come together to create the final result.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I did guess high connective tissue - do you actually need to know which specific high connective tissue cut it is?

Comment: @Jefromiwe need to know whether that is true or not

Answer (score 1):

Stack the slices up neatly, tie them together with some string and either use a slow-cooker (crockpot), or steamer to finish the cooking

Cook for at least the amount of time it missed on plus about 5 to 10 minutes for it to get back up to cooking temperature

The other option is to cut it up and add use it to make a new stew or casserole

Comment: Slow cooker with no liquid?