# Can I make baked veal more soft?

Tags: oven, steaming, veal

I usually cook meat in a steamer or multicooker, and it gets very soft. This time I've decided to experiment and baked a big chunk of veal stuffed with garlic in the oven.

Not that result was dissapointing, but it is definitely far from what I've expected. It tastes more like, well, cold boiled pork. So its very dry.

My question is - can I "save" the situation and convert already baked chunk of meat to something that tastes let it put this way more soft?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/42714/67

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how far overcooked it is, then you might be able to resuscitate it by cutting it into smaller pieces and cooking it low and slow in some liquid.

For example, you could use it as the meat in a stew, or slice it thinly and then braise it with some vegetable to make a pot-roast.

This also gives you an opportunity to introduce additional flavor, as it sounds as if that may have been lacking as well.

Comment: And I forgot to mention -- when slicing it, you want to cut across the grain, as this will have a major impact on how easy it is to chew.  (even if you don't cook it for additional time., but moreso if you cook it further).

Answer (score 3):

When I mess up a roast (I screwed up brisket for years), I would shred it and make some chili with some added ground meat.

Slicing super thin and putting it on a sammy with some mayo or horseradish can mask the toughness as well.